# MySQL Stored Procedure, define CURSOR FOR with variable

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, cursor

I am creating a stored procedure in MySQL to loop over a set of values and perform the same INSERT/UPDATE actions on each of those values.

The INSERT/UPDATE actions stay the same, but the values that need to be looped over change throughout the script I am writing. Below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `log_feed_times`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE `no_more_rows` BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE `current_animal` INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE `animal` CURSOR FOR @query;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_rows = TRUE;
    OPEN `animal`;
    chores: LOOP
    FETCH `animal` INTO `current_animal`;
    IF no_more_rows = TRUE THEN
        LEAVE move_now;
    END IF;

    UPDATE farm_animal SET last_feed_time = now() WHERE id = `animal`;

    END LOOP chores;
    CLOSE `animal`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

SET @query = "SELECT id FROM farm_animal WHERE name IN ('horse', cow')";

CALL `log_feed_times`;

SET @query = "SELECT id FROM farm_animal WHERE name IN ('pig', 'duck')";

CALL `log_feed_times`;
```

So far my attempts to do this have resulted in ERROR 1064 (42000).

Answer (score 0):

1. You should have used `current_animal` instead of `animal` in your update query.

```
 UPDATE farm_animal SET last_feed_time = now() WHERE id = current_animal;
```

2. The Loop  to leave should be `chores`

```
 IF no_more_rows = TRUE THEN
        LEAVE chores;
    END IF;
```